# How to find limit $\lim_{h\rightarrow0^-}\frac{e^{-1/|h|}}{h^2}$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

How can I find limit $$\lim_{h\rightarrow0^-}\frac{e^{-1/|h|}}{h^2}$$

I solve subproblem: $$\lim_{h\rightarrow0^-}\frac{e^{-1/|h|}}{h} = \lim_{h\rightarrow0^-}\frac{1}{e^{1/|h|}\cdot h} =\lim_{y\rightarrow -\infty}\frac{y}{e^{|y|}}=0$$
but I have no idea how to apply that for main target

Comment: **Hint:** $e^{-1/|h|}\le\frac1{1+\frac1{|h|}+\frac1{2|h|^2}+\frac1{6|h|^3}}\le6|h|^3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that, since you have the limit for $h\to0^-$, the substitution $y=1/h=-1/|h|$ brings the limit into the form
$$
\lim_{y\to\infty}\frac{y^2}{e^y}
$$
Now *any* limit of the form
$$
\lim_{y\to\infty}\frac{y^k}{e^y}
$$
with $k>0$ can be dealt with the substitution $y=kz$, so you get
$$
\lim_{z\to\infty}\frac{k^kz^k}{e^{kz}}=k^k\lim_{z\to\infty}\left(\frac{z}{e^z}\right)^{\!k}
$$
Thus you just need to know that $\lim_{z\to\infty}z/e^z=0$.

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to prove $$\lim_{y \to +\infty} \frac{y^2}{e^y} = 0$$ using the limit you provided.

Notice that you may write:
$$\frac{y^2}{e^y} = \frac{y}{e^{y/2}}\cdot \frac{y}{e^{y/2}} = 4 \cdot \frac{y/2}{e^{y/2}} \cdot \frac{y/2}{e^{y/2}}$$

Now you just have to substitute $z = y/2$ and take the limit $\frac{z}{e^z} \to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

To use your result, substitute $h\mapsto2h$ and square:
$$
\lim_{h\to0^-}\frac{e^{-1/|h|}}{(2h)^2}=\left(\lim_{h\to0^-}\frac{e^{-1/|2h|}}{2h}\right)^2=0
$$